# Exibir balão popup sobre um Label

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-5

Gostaria de exibir uma pequena mensagem para o usuário, estilo aqueles quando se passa o mouse, se não me engano seria o atributo

> alt="minha mensagem"

porém estou usando asp.net-mvc-5 e estou encontrando dificuldades para fazer. Minha mensagem, gostaria que aparecesse no **@Html.LabelFor**, e também queria que fosse uma mensagem fixa, acredito que com CSS, jquery ou javascript eu consiga fazer, mas não encontrei nada que me ajudasse.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Celular, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Celular, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control celular", id = "txt-tel" } })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Celular, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Isto que você quer](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)?

Comment: Semelhante a isto, porém a ideia maior, seria que fosse exibido um balãozinho ao carregar a página, e ele sumisse quando o usuário passasse o mouse em cima, mas neste formato já me ajuda.

Comment: [Assim, então](http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/javascript-tooltip)?

Comment: Isso, Obrigado @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você quer é um Tooltip. Há várias bibliotecas que fazem isso. Possivelmente você quer alguma que se comporte [como esta aqui](http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/javascript-tooltip).

Tooltips são em JS, então independem do ASP.NET MVC. O uso é feito da seguinte forma:

```
<span class="tooltip" onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this, 'Este é meu texto na tooltip.')">
    Exemplo de texto com Tooltip
</span>
```

Comment: Quando atribuo a classe tooltip meu conteúdo fica oculto

Comment: Veja os exemplos no site que passei. Tem mais exemplos de uso.